# How to return 202 Accepted in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I had trying to make a Flask application.
I want make some file like this:

```py
# ...
@app.route("/search") # Because Lynx can't play JavaScript
def search():
    # Return an 202 Accepted
    # Very long times searching...
    # Return result
# ...
```

So how can I let it return a 202 Accepted but don't return from the function?

Comment: This is not possible and is not really supported using common web standards since there might be an error after 202 is returned but before the result is returned. Hence, the status code should be send together with the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread

@app.route("/search"):
def search():
    def my_thread():
        # Search
        # Store the result somewhere so that a separate request
        # can be done to get result
    thread = Thread(target=my_thread)
    thread.start()
    return "Long request", 202
```

You might want to use something like Celery, it's built for doing asynchronous tasks

Comment: But how can I return 200 OK when the execution is completed?

Comment: You can't, because the request completed... A separate call may be made to check the status of the long request (whether it completed)

Answer (score -2):

> return a 202 Accepted but don't return from the function

This is impossible, as [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-return_stmt) put it

> `return` leaves the current function call with the expression list (or
> `None`) as return value.

So `return` does terminates function, this does hold for `python` as whole (is not limited to `flask`)

Comment: I don't think "return" needs to be taken literally here. OP asks whether they can *send a 202 response* to the client…

Comment: You're right. But even if returned, you can continue to perform that time-consuming task.